# KIE-TS-300B turbidity sensor not working

Tags: sensors, arduino-micro

I'm working with a clone Arduino micro board. I've got the color sensor up and running fine. So the problem isn't the card.

I'm using the example code, just to try out the module:

```cpp
        // the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
    void setup() {
      // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
    void loop() {
      // read the input on analog pin 0:
      int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
      // print out the value you read:
      Serial.println(sensorValue);
      delay(1);  // delay in between reads for stability
    }
```

A0 is on the output, ground and 5V wires are setup right. The red light on the module is red. I'm getting readings about 200-ish. That's about 1.5 V, if I convert it. I can't block it with an opaque object, that doesn't change the readings. I removed the cover, to see if it helps, still the same. I've tried three different sensors.

The one I'm using is this device: [TS-300B Turbidity sensor water turbidity module turbidity detection module](https://www.elecrow.com/ts-300b-turbidity-sensor-water-turbidity-module-turbidity-detection-module.html).

Any suggestions as to how, and why, is this happening?